# u-boot - Source object has EABI version 5, but target has EABI version 0

Tags: u-boot

When I try to compile u-boot I get the following error:

[image]

The error is explained in this link:

> http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/SourceObjectHasEABIVersion4ButTargetHasEABIVersion0

However, I don't know where to change in the source code.

Comment: Try a different toolchain, such as one from [gnuarm.com](http://www.gnuarm.com/), under the "Files" tab.  If you're not building for ARM Cortex, but something like 926ej-s, then GCC 3.4 is a proven toolchain for bootloaders.

Comment: It works for another toolchain. However, I want to learn that if there is a way to compile it with the current toolchain as explained in the link above.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174275/source-and-target-have-different-eabi-versions/52879467#52879467

Answer (score 1):

I changed the line

```
PLATFORM_CPPFLAGS +=$(call cc-option,-mapcs-32,-mabi=apcs-gnu)
```

in cpu/arm926ejs/config.mk to

```
PLATFORM_CPPFLAGS +=$(call cc-option,-mapcs-32,-mabi=aapcs-linux)
```

This time, I get the following errors:

```
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/lpc3250/toolchain-final-armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.5.3/libgcc.a(_dvmd_lnx.o): In function `__aeabi_ldiv0':
/home/timesys/work/ea313x_factory/factory-HEAD/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/libgcc/../gcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.asm:1265: undefined reference to `raise'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/lpc3250/toolchain-final-armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.5.3/libgcc.a(bpabi.o):(.ARM.exidx+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/lpc3250/toolchain-final-armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.5.3/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o):(.ARM.exidx+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/lpc3250/toolchain-final-armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.5.3/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o):(.ARM.exidx+0x0): undefined reference to `__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr0'
```

It seems that the problem relates to libgcc.a.

What I learnt is u-boot compiles with very few compilers.

The link

> http://communities.mentor.com/community/cs/archives/arm-gnu/msg02478.html

explains my problem as

> This is a simple problem to fix. First you need to understand that the
>   ARM EABI and ARM GNU/Linux toolchains are different. The Linux kernel
>   and applications are compiled with ARM GNU/Linux toolchain, while
>   bootloaders are compiled with ARM EABI toolchain.
>
> U-boot is a bare-metal application, therefore use the ARM EABI
>   toolchain. That is the best way to compile U-boot and other non-Linux
>   applications. It is possible to compile U-boot with Linux toolchain
>   but not recommended.