# Source and target have different EABI versions

Tags: arm, toolchain, eabi

I'm trying to compile a .so file using an ARM toolchain. However I keep getting this error-

> error: Source object has EABI version 0, but target  has EABI version 5

I can't change anything in the tool chain as I have to use the one given. I've never seen this error before.

I used this compiler flag - 
 `-Wl,--no-warn-mismatch`
But had to take it out as it broke a lot of other stuff.

The compiler flags I'm using are:
`-fPIC -O2 -marm -march=armv7-a`

Comment: You don't say which toolchain or target OS?  For the GCC, you have `-mabi=name`, where name is one of *apcs-gnu*, *atpcs*, *aapcs*, *aapcs-linux* or *iwmmxt*.  Although it sounds like you might not have an ELF file or something.  Try `file test.o` to see what type of file you have created from the compile stage.  I think *aapcs* is the more recent version (at least it is not version **zero**).

Comment: A little googling gives https://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiPort which might be helpful.

Comment: Yup, certainly smells like you're trying to link OABI and EABI objects together (having just tried that, it certainly produces the exact same error). What to do about it mostly depends on all the details that you haven't included in the question...

Answer (score 1):

**Use `as -meabi=5`**

I'm not going to claim I fully understand it... :-) but it solved the problem.

What I was trying to do that failed:

- assemble with GNU AS compiled from master at 4de5434b694fc260d02610e8e7fec21b2923600a configured with `--target arm-elf`
- link with Ubuntu 16.04 `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` version 5.3.1

I think that the value is mentioned in the EABI specs say something along about it http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044f/IHI0044F_aaelf.pdf

> Table 4-2, ARM-specific e_flags
>
> This masks an 8-bit version number, the version of the ABI to which this
> ELF file conforms. This ABI is version 5. A value of 0 denotes unknown
> conformance.

although I don't know why exactly 0 popped up at all.